# LoadLibraryEx ERROR_INVALID_ORDINAL

Tags: c++, dll, plugins, loadlibrary, vst

I developed a plugin which can be used among other plugins inside a host application.

At some point my plugin calls an external library, using `LoadLibraryExA(pathToLibrary,NULL,LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR | LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32);`

Everything works fine... Except when there is another, specific plugin that is also loaded before my plugin. I don't have access to the source code of that other plugin.
When that other plugin is loaded before my plugin, my LoadLibraryEx call fails, and GetLastError returns `ERROR_INVALID_ORDINAL`.

Any idea what that other plugin could be doing that is messing up with my LoadLibraryEx call ? Any way I could shield my plugin from that ?

thanks !

Comment: Sounds lie that other plugin loads a different version of that library, from a different location, so your search path is ignored and you get to use what's loaded.

Comment: If you could control the plugin load order, you could try loading yours 1st, but there's a chance that the other will fail when referencing your version of the *.dll*.

Comment: Hard to tell if there's a library conflict happening deep down (I use LoadLibraryEx to call my own library, but my own library depends on other libraries itself).
However I sort of "fixed" the issue by loading my library early. The other plugin still work when my plugin is loaded first.